# Adjust position of labels in xyplot in R

Tags: r, plot, raster, lattice, levelplot

I am making an xyplot in R. Everything went well except the labels positions. The labels are overlapping each other. Is there any way to separate the labels clearly e.g., using arrows, etc.? See my code below:

```
library(rasterVis)
library(raster)
library(colorRamps)
library(lattice)
df <- structure(list(x = c(-97.8198, -97.5489, -116.6933, -99.42, -99.5975, -98.0402, -97.4888, -96.8362, -103.65, -93.6906, -84.3324, -109.39, -106.1187, -101.8466, -111.7273, -105.1019, -111.762, -111.7718, -89.8735, -97.5684, -96.5603, -86.4131, -92.2, -96.4766, -96.4701, -96.4397, -105.5464, -116.7356, -116.7486, -116.7132, -96.902, -84.2874, -106.2618, -110.0522, -96.855), y = c(36.8193, 36.8085, 36.7653, 36.4267, 36.6358, 35.5497, 36.6058, 44.3453, 44.158, 41.9749, 35.9311, 38.09, 41.068, 43.95, 35.1426, 48.3077, 35.089, 35.4454, 34.2547, 38.7745, 39.0824, 39.3232, 38.7441, 41.1651, 41.1649, 41.1797, 40.0329, 43.1439, 43.0645, 43.1675, 43.2408, 35.9588, 40.7838, 31.7438, 37.5208), z = c(0.6, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 0.7, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 1.7, 1.2, 0.7, 1.3, 1.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 0.8, 1.1, 0.6, 1, 1.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 2.9, 0.8, 2.4, 1), ID = c("A32", "A74", "ADR", "AR1", "AR2", "ARb", "ARM", "Bkg", "Blk","Br1","ChR", "Cop", "CPk", "Ctn", "Fmf", "FPe", "Fuf", "Fwf", "Goo", "KLS", "Kon","MMS","MOz", "Ne1", "Ne2", "Ne3", "NR1", "Rls", "Rms", "Rws", "SFP", "WBW", "Wdn", "Whs","Wlr")), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")
df$z <- round(df$z,1)
x <- df$x
y <- df$y
d <- data.frame(lon=x, lat=y)
coordinates(d) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(d) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84
z <- df$z
col=colorRampPalette(rev(palette(matlab.like2(10))))
pp <- levelplot(z ~ x+y, xlim=c(-125,-65), ylim=c(25,50 ), panel = panel.levelplot.points, cex= 1.5, contour = T, margin = T, col.regions = col, colorkey=list( at=seq(0.2, 3, length=10), col=col ), at=seq(0.2, 3, length=10),xlab = list("Longitude", cex = 1.5), ylab = list("Latitude", cex=1.5), scales = list(tck = c(1,0), cex=1)) + xyplot(y ~ x, data = df,panel = function(y, x, ...) {ltext(x = x, y = y, labels = df$ID, cex = 1.2, font = 2,
             fontfamily = "serif",pos=2)
     })
```

Comment: Do you really need 14 libraries for your 10-line example?

Comment: I think only libraries rastervis, raster, colorRamps, and lattice will be required.

Comment: [This package](https://github.com/m-jahn/lattice-tools) has a `panel.repellabels` function which may be worth trying . Otherwise you could port your code to ggplot2 and use ggrepel [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542685/how-to-jitter-remove-overlap-for-geom-text-labels?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: ... https://github.com/m-jahn/lattice-tools#paneldirectlabels looks like it should work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).